# Azure Data Factory- How to create a table from snowflake view

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

Below is the scenario

I have two snowflake account - account-1 and account-2

we need to pull the view definition from account-1 and create the respective table in account-2 in snowflake.
Currently we are creating table manually from account-1 using describe view command.
Due to some reason both account cannot be shared.
we want to automate this process using ADF  since that is being asked to use for daily refresh between two account.

The following command doesn't work in the account-1 since its a shared database

```
select get_ddl('view', 'view_name')
```

so thought of using

```
describe view view_name
```

But the above command return all definition about the view other than column name and data type in a table format with in snowflake.
Now how can use ADF in this case to create a table from account-1 into the account2.

#What i tried

Using databricks to create table programmatically, but again that is restricted with in the project.

Any solution?

Comment: Have you investigated why you cannot share the data between the two accounts - as that is likely to be a much easier solution than using ADF?

Comment: As per the client, they don't encourage enabling data share between two account due to cost and certain policy restriction

Comment: 1) If there's a policy restriction then surely you shouldn't be sharing the data between accounts by any method - Snowflake sharing or ADF? 2) Building an operating an ADF solution is almost certainly going to be more expensive than Snowflake data sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can get column metadata from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view.

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'MY_SCHEMA' and table_name = 'MY_VIEW'
order by ordinal_position
```

With that you can dynamically build a SQL statement for CREATE TABLE.